# Angular Lazy loading components not being show as the URL navigate to the correct URL

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, loading, lazy-evaluation

Im Building Angular7 apps with multi screens.
and Im using lazy Loading.
cant figured right why the screens not showing in the lazy loading inner modules. (THE URL IS CHANGED BUT THE COMPONENT IS NOT SHOWING EVEN IF I PUT router-outlet in the parent)

```
*********app.routing.module.ts*******

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: '', component: HomepageComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'search', component: SearchOutletComponent,
        loadChildren: './personal-info/personal.module#PersonalModule'
      },
      { path: "y", component: DateReport},
      { path: "test", component: TestReport},


    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'Login', children: [
      { path: '', component: LoginComponent }
    ]
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'Login' }

];



*********Personal.routing.module.ts*******

const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'personal-info', component: PersonalInfoOutletComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: PersonalInfoComponent },
      {
        path: 'fund',
        loadChildren: './fund-details/fund.module#FundlModule',
      },
    ]
  },
  { path: '', component: SearchComponent },

];


*******Fund Module*******

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: FundDetailsComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations:
        [
            FundDetailsComponent
        ],
    imports: [
        SharedModule,
        CommonModule,
        PersonalModule,
        MaterialModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    entryComponents: [UserDetailsComponent]
})
export class FundlModule { }
```

SO when im trying to Naivgete to
**localhost:4200/search/personal-info/fund** << I SEE THE LAZY LOADING IS LOADED in F12, and the url IS changed! but the component of fund is not showing. instead i GET THE Component of this Route "{ path: '', component: SearchComponent },"
AND I CANT FIGURE IT WHY? if i remove this path, i get the the proper fund component as expected.

all the component such as

```
 SearchOutletComponent,PersonalInfoOutletComponent
```

`have "<router-outlet></router-outlet>` Inside so they show they children.

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules. Notice that when the examples use loadChildren on a route, the route never has a component. It's one or the other.

Comment: @JB Nizet Because they are using it on the root Module (app.module.ts) so they dont need.

Comment: Or because they use the feature correctly and you don't?

Comment: i remove the SearchOutletComponent and nothing changed, still got the same issue. so i guess its not so the problem. as u can see in the second lazy loading 
 (fund) i dont have an outletcomponent so i guess its dosent really matter.

Comment: Post a complete minimal example as a stackblitz.